# If I wanted to have SharePoint update with Live Market Data (ie. Bloomberg), is this possible?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, metadata, data

I'm trying to figure out if SharePoint has a functionality where it can feed in live Market Data from an external site (i.e. Bloomberg) and update periodically throughout the course of the day.

Answer (score 1):

there are couple of 3rd party solutions available for live stock quota updates.

**Free from CodePlex.**

This .Net assembly BCS external system provides live, read only data on Dow Jones 30 stocks details from MSN money webservices.

[BCS to provide stock information in SharePoint 2013](http://bcsstockinfo.codeplex.com/)

Or you can try this:

This recipe calls for some JavaScript, HTML, and a smidgen of YQL (Yahoo Query Language). Mix all these ingredients and serve it in style in the new SharePoint 2013 ‘Script Editor’ web part.

[How to Display Stock Information in SharePoint 2013](http://community.rightpoint.com/blogs/viewpoint/archive/2014/02/25/how-to-display-stock-information-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a webpart on this website,
https://www.sharepinpoint.com/index.php/2020/11/19/live-stock-quotes/

seems to work with SharePoint online as well.